# Decomposition of symmetric matrices over $\mathbb{F}_2$

Tags: matrices, finite-fields, matrix-decomposition, symmetric-matrices

Can every $n\times n$ symmetric matrix over $\mathbb{F}_2$ be decomposed into $$\sum_{v=1}^k v_i v_i^T$$ for vectors $v_1, \dots,v_k\in\mathbb{F}_2^n$ and integer $k$?

As far as I know, for symmetric real matrices this is true and these vectors are orthogonal, but I am not sure if these properties hold over finite fields.

Comment: I think that over the reals you need the extra assumption that the matrix should be positive semi-definite. I don't see a way of getting negative numbers on the diagonal otherwise. Of course, in the real case it might make sense to allow terms of the form $\lambda_iv_iv_i^T$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is definitely possible over $\Bbb{F}_2$. If $v$ is the column vector with $1$s at positions $i$ and $j$ and zeros elsewhere, $i<j$, then $vv^T$ has $1$s at positions $(i,i),
(i,j),(j,i)$ and $(j,j)$. Similarly if $w$ has a single $1$ at position $i$, then $ww^T$ has a single $1$ on the diagonal.

We can write every symmetric matrix as a linear combination of these. Use vectors of the first type to get the non-diagonal entries, and then "fix" the diagonal with vectors of the second type.

On the other hand, asking for orthogonality is a bit strange given that over $\Bbb{F}_2$ vectors are often orthogonal to themselves. Anyway, to get the symmetric matrix
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&1\cr1&0\cr}
$$
you need to use all the three non-zero vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3\in\Bbb{F}_2^2$, and $k=3$ is the smallest possible value. The conclusion is that we cannot ask for the vectors $v_i$ to be linearly independent.

At this time I don't want to say anything about the minimal required $k$ that works for larger matrices :-)

Comment: Initially I was lead astray by the fact that to write a symmetric matrix $A$ over $\Bbb{F}_2$ in the form $A=BB^T$ we sometimes need $B$ to have $n+1$ columns. Took me an embarrassing amount of time to realize that this fact is totally irrelevant for the purposes of the question at hand :-)